# Codeigniter Pagination showing that I am on the last page

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

So here is what I had before. If I'd go to ciblog/categories/posts/5/, it would take me to a page showing all posts with a category with the id of 5.

And here is what I want to do. I want to go to ciblog/categories/posts/5 and it would show be 5 posts lets say. Then when I go to ciblog/categories/posts/5/3 it would offset by 3 so now I have the next 3 posts.

Currently I have 4 posts, just for testing. If I directly through my url go to ciblog/categories/posts/5 it shows 3 posts, and if I go to ciblog/categories/posts/5/3 it shows my one other post, so the amount of posts I am getting is correct based on the url.

BUT at the bottom it always shows that I am on page 2. When I use F12 and look at the elements both my pagination links show ciblog/categories/posts/5
So its not adding on the number at the end

Here is what I have for the pagination for this page. I used print_r and everything in $config is correct.

```
public function posts($id, $offset=0){

    $category = $this->category_model->get_category($id);

    if(empty($category))
    {
        show_404();
    }
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'categories/posts/'.$id;
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->post_model->get_posts_by_category_count($id);
    $config['per_page'] = 3;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $config['attributes'] = array('class' => 'pagination-link');
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data['title'] = $category->name;
    $data['posts'] = $this->post_model->get_posts_by_category($id,$config['per_page'],$offset);

    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('posts/index', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');

}
```

Routes:

```
$route['categories/posts/(:num)/(:num)'] = 'categories/posts/$1/$2';
```

**Reference:**

I have been following a tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WoQTjJepDWM&index=8&list=PLillGF-RfqbaP_71rOyChhjeK1swokUIS
Code for this tutorial is here: https://github.com/bradtraversy/ciblog

I am now adding on to this. The only changes I have made are shown above

Comment: can you show what's on your posts view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url().'categories/posts/'. $id . '/' . $offset;
$config['uri_segment'] = 4;
```

Because your pagination depends on offset, not id of category, then you should let it find for the offset with uri_segment 4, and your base_url must send an offset variable to find the offset.

Comment: When I used $config['base_url'] = base_url().'categories/posts/'. $id . '/' . $offset; what ended up happening is it would make a url of ciblog/categories/posts/5/0/3

I removed it and just left the uri_segement as 4 and it worked. So it works now

Comment: Yeah, good for you. And if you use uri_segment like that, you don't need routes to do that, routes just makes your url shorter or something else.